# How to install a "virtual" network card on a virtual server?

Tags: networking, virtualization, hosting, web-hosting

We have purchased an unmanaged VPS windows hosting solution from one of the UK based companies. We have Windows Server 2008 Standard Edition.

We need to install certain third party applications on that server. Unfortunatelly, one of the applications requires a MAC address to be present at all times - this is their way of making sure that software is not pirated (which it isn't).

We have tried installing a virtual loopback network card, but this has brought the server down - i.e. we couldn't connect using remote desktop any longer.

At the moment we are limited with what we can try. This is an unmanaged solution, therefore any support including restarts is rather costly.

Are you aware of any low-risk solutions?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to sort this is to speak to your VPS provider as it's them and their hypervisor that define how many vNICs your server gets and how their MAC addresses are setup and assigned - there's very little you can do from your position.

Comment: Thank you. I guess the alternative is to go for the dedicated server, but this would increase monthly cost from around £35 to 90..at least. I was hoping that Microsoft had a way to install some sort virtual NIC..

Comment: They'll be able to sort you out but you just need to tell them what you're trying to do that's all - if I were them it's a 30 second job (you may need to shutdown your VM for a moment to allow them to change settings though).

Comment: After speaking to support...there is a virtual NIC available with a MAC address. It appears that the application requires a physical network card.

Comment: On other hand, the application ran internally few months ago on one of the VMWare solutions and we didn't have any issues.

Comment: odd..., speak to your software vendor then.

Comment: It appears that you were write. Based on third party feedback the Hyper-V makes it impossible to run parts of the application, when the VMWare ESxI solution is fully compatible. Decided to migrate to VMWare. :)

Answer (score 1):

Would installing a [LoopBack Adaptor](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winservergen/thread/df1dbf9f-58fa-4ac1-b019-8f86863371b7) on your 2008 install provide a suitable MAC?

Comment: This has taken the server down yesterday...site was up and running, but the remote connection was not possible.

Comment: How strange... can't suggest anything else I'm afraid.